# CSS Inherit and em-units not rendering properly

Tags: css

I have some HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

And some css

```
body {font-size:2em}
li {font-size:60%}
li:nth-child(2){font-size:inherit}
```

And all is good

[image]

If I **replace the li font-size with an em unit** the inheritance breaks

```
body {font-size:2em}
li {font-size:1em}
li:nth-child(2){font-size:inherit}
```

[image]

What, o dear gods of css, may cause this?

See fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/3ho1uc3u/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In CSS, if you give a relative unit, it is by default relative to the size you inherit from.
In your case if you use 1em is like you set font-size: 100%.

```
li {font-size:0.6em}
```

```css
body {font-size:2em}
li {font-size:0.6em}
li:nth-child(2){font-size:inherit}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

> EMs do work like percentages in that the base font size is always 1em
>   and .6em would be 60% of that (in the same way 1.2em would be
>   equivalent of 120% of base font size).

Answer (score 1):

`1em` is one unit of the inherited font size.

So if you set `2em` on the body, then `1em` inherited by the `li` is actually `2em` of the size that `body` inherited at first place (in your case the default `16px` of the browser.)

```
body           {font-size:2em}
li             {font-size:1em}     /* will be 2em of the inherited size by body*/
li:nth-child(2){font-size:inherit} /* will be 2em of the inherited size by body*/
```

Both `li` types will have the same font size.

The first one has 1 unit (or `1em`) of the inherited `2em`, the second one inherits `2em` directly.